# How to reduce development database to smaller size?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

The problem is in this:
I have a dump of staging database that I am using in development and the database size is around 2 Gb which makes many of the ActiveRecord commands (mostly 'where' commands) to run for at least 5 minutes.

**What could be a solution(s) to speed up this in 'development'?**

Some of the options would be to create a partial database of the development (haven't investigated how), caching, which for some reason didn't work or there is some other option. I would even consider hardcoding some part of the ActiveRecord calls, just to acheave this in development mode.

Comment: Another common solution is to create a fourth environment called "staging". So basically you can have a seeded DB in development and a then try your app out on "real" data in the staging environment.

Comment: You make a new environment just by adding a new file in `config/environments` and an extra entry in `database.yml`. You can copy either `development.rb` or `production.rb` depending on if you intend to run staging on a server which is accessable from the internet.

Comment: Not sure I understand the first comment, although from the first look at it, seems the one that would result in the same loading times. As for the second, well, I wouldn't want to use remore database as a development database. If there is some other options then those two?

Comment: The idea is that you have a development environment with a limited set of data - usually created from a seed file for development and debugging. And another environment that mirrors the production environment as closely as possible. So yes it does solve your issue.

Comment: Turning on catching on development is not a good solution since you want changes to be immediate in dev. And the only real way to make SQL queries faster is by using indices and making sure the queries are optimized.

Comment: You also misunderstood completely - your dev database is local, staging is often remote and shared by the whole team and automatically mirrors the prod database but it does not have to be.

Comment: @max You say that the development will have a limited set of data, but I am not sure where you have explained how to create development with limited set of data? How to create development database with a limited set of data from the production site? Also, caching might be an option as I am mostly reading the data, not so much updating

Comment: Use a seed file with random data or mirror the production database and trim down the amount of data. You don't want query caching or any other sort of caching happening in dev - believe me. It can be extremely aggravating trying to debug something and your changes are not taking due to cache.

Comment: Ok, we then get to the main question - how to trim that data? If I have, for example a project id = 1, and 30 milion records of `user_data`, where the the 2million-th record is related to the project id = 1. How to trim the data, so the actual data that I will trim will have some sense when I run a development database?

Comment: Thats entirely specific to your app and impossible for somebody who does not work on your project to answer.

Comment: Ok, then I don't really get what you were trying to solve in the comments of this question? (not that I don't appreciate the effort). That is not that specific to the project. You have gems which can partially do something like this https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump , but that could be only a part of the solution.

Comment: I'm trying to explain a common working solution which I have used on projects with huge databases. How are we supposed to know how you would untangle the associations in your project? Any advise would be so broad as to be meaningless.

Comment: I got it. So, one solution would be not to use that database in development, create a seed file, and use that seed file in development, and test on staging on real data if and when needed? And the second solution would be to have a development database hosted remotely, and run queries on a remote database? @max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to achieve this based on the info you've provided.

As mentioned in the comments, you could create a seed file and build a few records to be used in development. This is common practice for most development databases (especially with more than one developer). [See the Rails guides about this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data)

Another idea would be to write a rake task that isolates a few relevant rows within the most dependent table in your staging database (say `users`) and build dummy data from that record. This might help you build "real-ish" data without having to do it all from scratch. If there's a large tangle of associations, this might be more work than it's worth.
Gem [seed_dump](http://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump) could come in handy for that pourpouse.

Word of caution, if that staging DB has any PII (personally identifiable information) you will likely want to obfuscate it so you aren't storing user information locally.

Comment: Thanks Bobby for the answer. Creating a seed file might be a bit time-consuming and might not worth it. Isolating the data with a rake task, might be a good idea, but on the other hand, just like you said, this is probably more work then it's worth. In my particular case, as the loading of the data is taking too fast and the data is mostly used `as-is`, I have cached that portion of the code for development environment in order to speed-up the loading times. Also,FYI for the first suggestion which you gave there is a gem that might be used for that purpose https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump